# Firebase functions results in error when writing to cloud storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a android app which uses firebase and calls a firebase function:

```
 const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(/*excluded from this question*/);
 const storageFilePath = 'storedjokes/' + '81' + '.json'; 
 console.log('pre parse:',data.jokejson);
try{
 await bucket.upload(data.jokejson, {
  destination: storageFilePath,
});
}catch(e){
  console.log('there was a error');
  console.log(e);
}
```

everything works until bucket.upload(),where firebase says:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory

Even though my data.jokejson is there. "storageFilePath" is a path that doesn't exist and I assume will be created automatically when I call bucket.upload(). Am I wrong about the path being automatically created,or is it some other problem?

Comment: The error message is complaining about your local file, not the remote path in storage.  I can only conclude, without seeing anything else here, that the named file doesn't actually exist.

Comment: what value is this `console.log('pre parse:',data.jokejson);` logging?

Comment: It outputs: pre parse: {"error":false,"category":"Miscellaneous","type":"twopart","setup":"Why was the river rich?","delivery":"Because it had two banks.","flags":{"nsfw":false,"religious":false,"political":false,"racist":false,"sexist":false},"id":184,"lang":"en"}

Comment: so it output the contents of the file, right? try using `data` only instead of `data.jokejson` on the `bucket.upload()` and let me know what come out of it.

Comment: data includes other information including: firebase tokens,so I shouldn't be passing all of that as a JSON

Comment: ok, but here is the problem then, `data.jokeson` is not the file itself, it's just the content of the file, correct? If that is the case, this will not work since you need to pass the file itself as a parameter to `bucket.upload()`.